# Jquery waypoints - destroy sticky when parent element is 50% passed

Tags: jquery, jquery-waypoints

Im sure this is simple but have been at it for a bit and cant seem to get the syntax right. I have a series of sections containing captions which are fixed to the top when the parent hits the top of the page. I want to destroy the sticky when the parent element is 50% past the top but cant seem to get it right.

Heres where I declare the waypoints - Ive tried writing a handler within this to target the captions and destroy the waypoint but I havent gotten it working.

```
        $('.content').each(function() {                 
        new Waypoint.Inview({
            element: this,
            enter: function(direction) {
                $(this.element).addClass('active')
            },
            exited: function(direction) {
                $(this.element).removeClass('active')
            }           
        })
        new Waypoint.Sticky({
            element: $(this).children('.caption')
        })
    });
```